# 2 same submit buttons - get correct form id after submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I use jquery 1.3.2. I have 2 same submit buttons with same id's in one page. Buttons have different form id's.

Both buttons have same id

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-submit-43" class="form-submit">
```

Both forms have different id's

```
<form action="/productxy" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="uc-product-kit-add-to-cart-form-43-1" class="ajax-cart-submit-form"></form>
```

How to get the id of the form of button that was clicked instead of button that is first in html?

Comment: Duplicate ids are not valid unless you are using HTML5. You should consider avoiding this.

Comment: @OptimusCrime - Duplicates IDs aren't valid in HTML5 either.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Looks like you are right. I've just overheard that somewhere and never bothered to double-check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your JS, but assuming you are binding a common click handler to the buttons or a common submit handler to the forms you would use `this` in combination with DOM traversal methods:

```
$(".form-submit").click(function() {
    // assuming the button is actually inside its associated form:
    var parentFormID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id");
});
```

or:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var myId = this.id;
});
```

Within an event handler `this` will refer to the element that the event applied to.

And note that it is not valid to have duplicate IDs.

Comment: var parentFormID = $(this).closest("form").attr("id"); this is what I was looking for thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**ID's in a HTML page are supposed to be unique.**

Change this to

```
<input type="submit" class="form-submit">
```

You can remove the `id` for button completely as it is not required

```
$('.form-submit').on('click', function() {

     var $form = $(this).closest('form');

     // this should give you the corresponding form 
     // in which the button is in

     var formId = $form.attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I understand but is there a solution in jquery to this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by a solution ?, you can always use `class` instead

Comment: I try to use your code but I get error - object has no method 'on'

Comment: Looks like you are using `jquery 1.3`  Try this `$('.form-submit').click(function() {`